# linux zip command creating temp name

Tags: linux, python, zip

I am creating a python script which will move the fresh zipped files to a hotfolder. But when i am creating a zip file with `zip test.zip /opt/test` it creates a temp file first, something like `xAbCG77`, then it renames it to `test.zip`, is there any way to create the zip files with the original name, or is there a way to track what is going to be the name of that file, is it a hash for the name?

Thanks.

Comment: But if it creates the zip file, and then renames it, you can't just wait until it renames and then move the final (correct name) file ?

Comment: i am running a scan in every five minutes, and i have some really heavy zip files which are getting created by other users on network.

Comment: @woliveirajr I think he is creating it directly in the hotfolder. The zip I use creates a temp-file in the **current** directory so you could try to execute the zip command in a different directory then the holtfolder and doing `zip /hotfolder/test.zip /opt/test`. You could also created somewhere else and move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your zip version. My zip creates the temp-file in the current directory.

You could try something like `zip - /opt/test > test.zip` but it depends on your zip-version if this works.

I would just do a `cd /tmp` and then execute `zip /hotfolder/test.zip /opt/test`. This way your temp-file is created in your `/tmp` and moved directly after **successful** creation.